# Embedding of a closed subspace of $L^1_m([0,1])$ with each element in some $L^p$ with $p>1$ in a higher $L^{p_0}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $S$ be a closed subspace of $L^1_m[0, 1]$ such that each $f\in S$ belongs to some $L^p_m[0, 1]$ with $p>1$. Prove that there exists a $p_0 > 1$ such that all $S$ is contained in $L^{p_0}_m[0,1]$.

My attempt: Since for finite measure spaces if $1\leq p\leq q<\infty$, $L_q\subseteq L_p$. So we can take the infimum of all such $p$. But I am not sure how to use the closeness or completeness of $S$ to say that the infimum is strictly greater than $1$.

And what is the counterexample when $S$ is not closed?

Comment: what does the $m$ subscript mean in $L^p_m$? is it the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Yeah it is Lebesgue measure.